# JavaFX8 tree table view custom root row

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, root-node, treetableview

In my tree-table-view I have a root item which contains child items(I have mistakenly called  them root items) that in turn have child items. I need to customize those mistakenly called root items rows text appearance. Is there such a selector or how else would that be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will set a pseudo-class on the row containing the root:

```
final PseudoClass firstRowClass = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("first-row");

treeTableView.setRowFactory(treeTable -> {
    TreeTableRow<...> row = new TreeTableRow<>();
    row.treeItemProperty().addListener((ov, oldTreeItem, newTreeItem) -> 
        row.pseudoClassStateChanged(firstRowClass, newTreeItem == treeTable.getRoot()));
    return row ;
});
```

Now you can select that row in css with

```
.tree-table-row-cell:first-row { ... }
```

Complete example [here](https://gist.github.com/james-d/11177668)

It sounds like you want to style the immediate child nodes of the root node. In this case, just do

```
    row.treeItemProperty().addListener((ov, oldTreeItem, newTreeItem) -> 
        row.pseudoClassStateChanged(firstRowClass, 
           newTreeItem != null && newTreeItem.getParent() == treeTable.getRoot()));
```

instead of the condition in the code above. Obviously, you can use other criteria as you need them (e.g. `! newTreeItem.isLeaf()`).

Note that the default style sheet rules for `tree-table-row` are a little strange: `-fx-background-color` is set for the row, but `-fx-text-fill` is set for both the row and the cells inside it. So if you want to change the background color, you just need

```
-tree-table-row-cell:first-row {
  -fx-background-color: antiquewhite ;
}
```

but if you want to change the text color, you need to change it on the cells:

```
-tree-table-row-cell:first-row .tree-table-cell {
  -fx-text-fill: red ;
}
```

Comment: I tried it and got it to work. If you're changing the text fill you probably need `.tree-table-row-cell:first-row .tree-table.cell { -fx-text-fill: red; }` in the external css (for some reason the text fill is specified in both `tree-table-row-cell` and `tree-table-cell` in `modena.css`).

Comment: still no luck..I don't know why, could it be that I have a global invisible root item which contains several visible root items?

Comment: yes it did, but it is the case I described in the comment above..there's only first global root item colored in red

Comment: I thought that's what you were looking for. You said "the root row". There is only one root ion a TreeView or TreeTableView.

Comment: Ok, I guess I should reformulate the question

Comment: Excellent! The updated answer(below the example) did the job. I apologize for the confusion created by the initial question. Thanks a lot!